# SQL - Test if data has been updated for today in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I'm trying to test if a DB2 table has been updated today.

I can get the latest update date:

```
SELECT DATE(REFRESH_TIME) as rfrsh_day
FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES
WHERE NAME in ('my_table');
```

and today's date:

```
SELECT current date as today FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

I want a TRUE if `rfrsh_day == today`, otherwise FALSE.  How would I compare these in a single SQL statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `case` statement:

```
SELECT (case when DATE(REFRESH_TIME) = CURRENT DATE then 'true' else 'false' end) as rfrsh_day
FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES
WHERE NAME in ('my_table');
```